# Concave mirror and convex mirror placed facing each other

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, reflection, geometric-optics

**A convex mirror in a concave mirror each of focal length f are placed coaxially. They are separated by 4f and their reflecting surfaces face each other. A point object is kept on the principle axis at a distance x from the concave mirror such that final image after two reflections, (first on the concave mirror) , is on the object itself find x in terms of f.**

*The solution is (3-√3) f*

I first used the mirror formula for concave mirror ie. 1/f=1/u+1/v and got the value v=fx/(f-x) Then as per the question says now we have to consider the convex mirror for reflection but convex mirror will form a image before reflecting surface(real image) when a virtual object is created behind the convex mirror by concave mirror therefore the distance should be {fx/(f-x)}-4f? Am i wrong? I am confused whether i should take the distance {fx/(f-x)}+4f or {fx/(f-x)}-4f.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You are struggling with sign convention in optics. That is really frustrating. In the figure $l$, $x$ and $f_0$ are all positive (as they should be in normal world)

Applying mirror equation for first reflection (from concave mirror)
$$\frac{1}{v} + \frac{1}{u} = \frac{1}{f}$$
$$\frac{1}{-l} + \frac{1}{-x} = \frac{1}{-f_0}$$

Solving we get,
$$l = \frac{f_0 x}{x-f_0}$$

Hopefully, you have spotted your mistake and know how to proceed from here. (Your 'distance' was negative!)